# Define the fill of the zoomed panel using facet_zoom in ggforce

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, ggforce

I want to fill the zoomed panel to match the default grey of facet_zoom in ggforce.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
   geom_point() +
   facet_zoom(x = Species == 'versicolor') +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]I want the zoomed panel also to have the grey background.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I presume could be done if you overwrite the `facet_zoom` function, which you could start with by editing the code in https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/blob/main/R/facet_zoom.R.  Not obvious to me at first read.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to modify `facet_zoom` and I was hoping someone might know of an elegant way to modify the color of the zoom panels like with `zoom.x = element_rect(fill = "grey", color = NA), zoom.y = element_rect(fill = "grey", color = NA)` within `theme`, but those only address the zoomed section of the un-zoomed panel and the callout to the zoomed panel.  I do have a more brute force way to do it using `annotate`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
    annotate("rect", xmin = data.table(iris)[Species == 'versicolor', min(Petal.Length)] * 0.965, xmax = data.table(iris)[Species == 'versicolor', max(Petal.Length)] * 1.02, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill="light grey", alpha=0.3) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_zoom(x = Species == 'versicolor') +
    theme_bw()
```

The challenge to to find the boundaries of the x and/or y axis when they're not explicit in `facet_zoom`.  I had to hunt and peck to get them to align.

[image]